# If a light beam is sent tangent across earth would it curve at 9.8 $\rm m/s^2$?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

Just to see if my understanding of the curvature of light is correct.

Comment: The question is clear enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will curve, but not at 9.8 m/s$^2$ as predicted by Newton's theory. Its curvature will be twice that value as predicted by General Relativity.

Comment: Can you share your calculation? A quick glance at Wald equation 6.3.15 made me believe the acceleration is three times that of slow objects, but I'm not at all sure if that's correct.

Comment: I also looked at the equation but I did not see a factor of 3. My 'calculation' is just handwaving with the factor of 2 between Newton (Einstein 1911) and GRT.

Comment: If you differentiate equation 6.3.15 with respect to $r$ to get acceleration, a factor of $3$ comes out for null-geodesics. Also there will be an additional small factor of $1-2MG \over {Rc^2}$. Also, that acceleration is with respect to proper time, but that's not a big deal as they are the same up to the first order.

Comment: Also, in this paper http://users.df.uba.ar/sgil/physics_paper_doc/papers_phys/cosmo/ligt_bend.pdf the difference between equations (1.1) and (1.2) is exactly the factor of $3$. I checked that (1.1) gives acceleration $g$, while (1.2) gives $3g$ (and the factor $1-2MG \over {Rc^2}$ appears if the Schwarzschild metric is used). So now I'm quite sure the answer is approximately $3g$. I don't know why this question was closed, it's a good question.

Comment: @mathquest I am puzzled, for how do you end up with a deflection angle that is twice that in Newton gravitation, if the acceleration at perigee is 3 times the Newton value?

Comment: That's only the perpendicular component of acceleration of light traveling parallel to Earth. For light traveling towards the centre, for example, the acceleration is zero. The path would be some trajectory, not a hyperbola, such that the overall angle of deflection is twice that of predicted by Newtonian gravity for objects with speed $c$.

Comment: @mathquest At perigee there is only perpendicular acceleration.

Comment: the factor of $2$ found by Einstein is overall deflection, not just infinitesimal deflection at perigee

Comment: @mathquest You should submit this as an answer even if I am not convinced :)

Answer (score 2):

For an observer at the surface of earth, close to the point where the beam is tangent to the surface, the equivalent principle is valid. The measured deflection is the same as it would happen in a rocket in space with an acceleration $g$.

But for an observer very far from earth, the total deflection is $2 \times$ the calculated considering an acceleration of $g$ on the beam.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

The beam of light would curve under the influence of gravity, because light goes as straight as it can through curved space.  Calculating the exact amount of curvature is relatively complex, given the Einstein equations.

Comment: So would it curve at 9.8 ms/s^2?

Comment: Very, very briefly.  Light goes so fast that it would be far far out of Earth's gravity in well under a second.  As I said, I'm not sure how the math would play out, light follows somewhat different rules from regular matter.  But it would definitely be deflected a very, very tiny amount on a near flyby of Earth.  Even skimming the sun light barely deflects.

Comment: It is clear that a beam light will be curved. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the light beam would curve at 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>, as per Newton's theory:

> To see why a deflection of light would be expected, consider Figure 2-17, which shows a beam of light entering an accelerating compartment. Successive positions of the compartment are shown at equal time intervals. Because the compartment is accelerating, the distance it moves in each time interval increases with time. The path of the beam of light, as observed from inside the compartment, is therefore a parabola. But according to the equivalence principle, there is no way to distinguish between an accelerating compartment and one with uniform velocity in a uniform gravitational field. We conclude, therefore, that **a beam of light will accelerate in a gravitational field as do objects with rest mass**. For example, near the surface of Earth light will fall with acceleration 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>.

[http://web.pdx.edu/~pmoeck/books/Tipler_Llewellyn.pdf](http://web.pdx.edu/%7Epmoeck/books/Tipler_Llewellyn.pdf)

Comment: But light doesn't curve "as per Newton's theory". This was shown in 1919.

Comment: I don't think Newton's theory says anything about bending light. GR though indeed says that if acceleration is the same for all objects, then it has to be the same for light by continuity (the curvature is zero). The problem with this reasoning is that it's not true in GR that fast moving objects will have the same acceleration near Earth as slow moving objects.

Comment: @mathquest Why is this a problem?

Comment: @my2cts the argument is that if every geodesic inside the light cone is a straight line in the coordinates given by the reference frame accelerating with $g$, then the light cone also has to consist of straight line geodesics. But if we don't know that about every other geodesic, we can not make the conclusion about the light cone.